# Is there any way to target two events together in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to define some hover properties using JavaScript. So, I decided to go with "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events for an element. Now, I have to call the same function for both the events in addEventListener.

So, is there any way of doing it like:

element.addEventListener("mouseenter" or "mouseleave", myfunc);

Comment: `['mouseenter', 'mouseleave'].forEach(type => element.addEventListener(type, myHandler));`

Comment: Just a heads up, make sure your hover events are only progressive enhancement, otherwise you alienate nearly 60% of web users, if this concerns you.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you need both events, then you should add two event listeners, so the syntax should look like this.

```
element.addEventListener("mouseenter", func);
element.addEventListener("mouseleave", func);
```

or

```
["mouseenter", "mouseleave"].forEach(event => {
  element.addEventListener(event, func);
})
```

It's the same thing